# Submit iframed form to a new window

Tags: php, html, iframe

My form is in an iframe, but I want the submitted form to be opened in a new window. How can this be done?

Comment: try `window.location` in javascript or in php you can use `header` or `redirect`

Comment: Try the `target` attribute in your `form` tag - `target="_parent"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the form tag, you simply need to set the "target" attribute just like:

```
<form target="some_target">
```

There are 5 different values for this attribute.

**_blank** : This will post the form to a completely new window.

**_self** : This is the default option. It posts to the same window or frame as the current form.

**_parent** : This posts to the parent of the current iframe.

**_top** : This posts to the topmost parent of the current iframe.

***framename*** : You can also name the target window yourself. Naming a target will open a new window, and let you post multiple times to that same window.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
<form action="form_action.php" target="_parent">
```

Answer (score 1):

The default `target` attribute for a `form` is `_self` which means, "submit to the `action` page and display the results in my frame." If the form is within an iFrame, then the results will be displayed in the iFrame.

In order to display the results in the parent frame, add `target="_parent"` to the `form` open-tag.

Answer (score 1):

Make this your form inside the iframe:

```
<form target="_parent" action="blubb.php">
    <input type="text" name="var1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```